# How to write image objects into a div

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, sorry if this is already asked, but I didn't find it :/

I have a 2D array with strings that will show images once written into a div.

I write them into the div by doing this inside two for circles:

```
myDiv.innerHTML += 2dArray[i][j];
```

So far so good, the images show up.

Next I pick the images into an array by doing:
images = myDiv.children;

The images now turned into objects which I put back into the 2D Array.

I change some of their attributes and then try to write them back into the div.

This is where it fails. I tried everything I know so far.

Tried:

- toSource();
- appendChild();

If any of these work, I probably used them wrong.

The div shows this:

```
[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],

[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement]
```

I want to display the images.

Comment: show us the code, like the actual code not pseudo code

Comment: This is not how you add an image to a div. Please show us the relevant part of your code so we can help you fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to again added them into you myDiv element. The img elements that you retrieved using `myDiv.children` are still attached to myDiv.

If you do something like the following, the first child will re-render with a red background

```
images = myDiv.children;
images[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) shows a way to insert images into a container element using

```
myDiv.appendChild(images[i][j]); //assuming images[i][j] is an HTMLImageElement
```

PS. `2dArray` is not a valid javascript variable name! Variable names shouldn't start with digits.